# efficently get nearest id based on counting a column in one-to-many table

Tags: sql, join, count, teradata, relational

I have a relational table (one-to-many) and I need to efficiently get the similarities between the ids giving they associated items. The table its something like this:

```
id  item 
1   A2231
1   A2134
2   A2134
2   B2313
...
```

What I need is to get how many rows are common between all the ids:

```
a_id  b_id  count_items
1     2     1 
1     3     0
2     1     1 
...
```

I have made a query, but Its o(n2), and it doesn't work because the spool space.

```
SELECT A.ID AS a_id, B.ID AS b_id, COUNT(B.item) AS count_items
FROM Tab AS A LEFT JOIN  Tab AS B --same table
ON (A.item = B.item)
GROUP BY A.ID, B.ID
```

> EDIT:

```
n_rows ~ 50MM 
n_items ~ 100K 
n_ids ~ 170K
combinations id/item are unique
```

It'a there a way to efficiently accomplish this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some stats: number of rows, number of items, rows per item max? Is the id/item combination unique?

Comment: @dnoeth edited ;)

Comment: Best possiblesolution: PI on `item` and if it's still spooling out you might run it against smaller subsets, e.g. 10,000 items per batch. Btw, you probably need to add another condition `(A.ID <> B.ID)`, otherwise you never get a zero count (and don't need an outer join).

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. PS "It's o(n2)" & "doesn't work because" are unhelpfully vague. The max result size is o(n2) in size of the inputs; that can't be helped. But that doesn't mean the result has to take that much temp memory. Nor that much time. Depends on implementation. In particular, on DDL indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by just using an inner join:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, COUNT(*) AS count_items
FROM Tab A LEFT JOIN
     Tab B --same table
     ON A.item = B.item
GROUP BY A.ID, B.ID;
```

Next, if your table has duplicates, then this might work:

```
with t as (
      select distinct id, item
      from tab
     )
select a.id, b.id, count(*)
from t a join
     t b
     on a.item = b.item
group by a.id, b.id;
```

And finally, if you want all pairs of items, then:

```
with t as (
      select distinct id, item
      from tab
     )
select i1.id, i2.id, count(b.id)
from (select distinct id from tab) i1 cross join
     (select distinct id from tab) i2 left join
     t a
     on t.id = i1.id left join
     t b
     on b.id = i2.id and a.item = b.item
group by i1.id, i2.id;
```

Comment: its still having problems with the space, it's there a way to not get into the o(n2) combination?